# Second Order Nonhomogeneous Differential Equation.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

The Eulero equation of the functional

$$J[y]=\int_a^b \frac{y'^2}{x^3} \; \mathrm dx,$$

leads to the following differential equation:

$$\frac{y''}{x^3}-3\frac{y'}{x^4}=0.$$

I rewrote the equation as

$$xy''-3y'=0,$$

integrating by parts I got:

$$y'x-4y=0.$$

and by separation of variables:

$$y=c_1x+c_2$$

which is not a solution of the original differential equation. 
Where did I commit illegal steps?

Comment: For $c_2 \ne 0$ this is not a solution of $y'x-4y=0.$

Comment: Don't forget the constant of integration when doing IBP:
$$xy'-4y=c$$
Solving gives:
$$y=k_1 x^4-\frac{c}{4}$$
$$y=k_1 x^4+k_2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a mistake with logarithms. Separating variables you get $$ \begin{align} \frac{y'}{y} &= 4 \frac{1}{x} \\ \implies \mathrm{ln}(y) &= 4 \mathrm{ln}(x) +c \\ \implies \mathrm{ln}(y) &= \mathrm{ln}(x^4) +c \\ \implies y &= Dx^4 \end{align} $$

Comment: what, for example, if $y=x^4+4$ then our equation doesn't hold $y'x-4y=0$, because we get $-16=0$?

Comment: $y=x^4+c$ is not correct ! Correct: $y=cx^4$

Comment: Ah, thank you, of course - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of $y'x-4y=0$ is given by

$y=cx^4$.

Comment: I know, but how did you get it?

Comment: You know ???  You have written $y=4x+c$ . Write $y'x=4y$. Then separation of variables.

Comment: @Dante I think you're making a mistake with exponentiating logarithms in one of your last steps in the separation of variables (easy mistake to make if you do it quickly!) More specifically, you get $\mathrm{ln}(y) = 4 \mathrm{ln}(x) = \mathrm{ln}(x^4)$, then exponentiate.

Comment: separating the variables, $\frac{y'}{y}=4\frac{1}{x}$ which gives rise to $\ln |y|=4\ln |x|+c$, right?

Comment: @AndrewWhelan oh god, yes it was my mistake. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dante No problem - an easy pitfall for this one (: